# Partition replication in case of messages directly posted to a partition in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

As per my understanding, the Producer and the Consumers write and read to the leader broker containing the leader partition. After the record is written to the leader partition, the record is replicated across the follower partition.

I have recently read that the Producer can explicitly write to a specific partition. Is this possible and if so, will the replication happen to other partition since it might not be the leader partition.

Answer (score 0):

> "I have recently read that the Producer can explicitly write to a specific partition. Is this possible [...]"

Yes, this is true. You can define a custom partitioner by implementing `Partitioner` and declare it in the KafkaProducer configuration `partitioner.class`

Here is an example of a custom partitioner in Java:

```java
public class MyPartitioner implements Partitioner {
  public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {}
  public void close() {}

  public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes,
                       Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {
    List<PartitionInfo> partitions = cluster.partitionsForTopic(topic);
    int numPartitions = partitions.size();

    if ((keyBytes == null) || (!(key instanceOf String)))
      throw new InvalidRecordException("Record did not have a string Key");

    if (((String) key).equals("myKey"))
       return 0; // This key will always go to Partition 0

    // Other records will go to the rest of the Partitions using a hashing function
    return (Math.abs(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % (numPartitions - 1)) + 1;
  }
}
```

> "[...] and if so, will the replication happen to other partition since it might not be the leader partition?"

You are mixing up partitions with replicas. Those are two independent concepts as partitions distribute the data of a topic into multiple locations to achieve parallelism whereas replication actually duplicates the data across the cluster for higher durability.

Using a custom partitioner will still ensure that your KafkaProducer will only communicate with and write the data to the partition leader.

Remember that each partition within a topic has a partition leader. You have as many partition leaders as you have partitions in a topic.

Comment: "Using a custom partitioner will still ensure that your KafkaProducer will only communicate with and write the data to the partition leader."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can explicitly write to a specific partition.
Each partition has a leader node and the rest of the nodes are followers.
When you write to a partition, it is written to the node that is the leader for that partition, and the follower nodes replicate that data.

For example, if you spin up a cluster with 3 broker nodes `(broker1, broker2, broker3)` and let's say you create a topic with 3 partitions `(0, 1, 2)` and configure it to have 2 replicas.

What happens in this case is that each broker will be leader for one partition, and replicas for the other two. Let's say:

```
partition 0 has leader as broker1 and replicas as broker2 and broker3
partition 1 has leader as broker2 and replicas as broker1 and broker3
partition 2 has leader as broker3 and replicas as broker1 and broker2
```

When you write to partition 0, it is written to it's leader node broker1 and then replicated to other nodes and similarly for the other partitions.

Even though broker2 is leader for partition 1, it is a follower for partition 0 and 2, and whatever messages need to be replicated from partition 0 or 2 will get written to broker2, since it is a leader only for partition 1.